# Lua find out what table a value is in

Tags: lua

Consider the following:

```lua
player = {}
player.shape = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 50, h = 50}
```

Is there a function in Lua that would tell me what table `player.shape` is in?
I want to be able to do something like this:

```lua
shape_a = player.shape
some_function(shape_a) = player
```

Comment: "`some_function(shape_a) = player`" What would that do?

Answer (score 8):

Why not just store a reference to the parent table in the shape?

```
player = {}
player.shape = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 50, h = 50, parent = player}
```

You can do that automatically with metamethods like this:

```
local new_player = function()
  return setmetatable(
    {},
    {
      __newindex = function(t,k,v)
        if k == "shape" then v.parent = t end
        rawset(t,k,v)
      end,
    }
  )
end

player = new_player()
player.shape = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 50, h = 50}
```

Now you can access the player from the shape by calling `shape.parent`.

Comment: Sounds good, although having a reference to the parent in the shape seems a little redundant. Still, if I can use metamethods to do it automatically, then it's actually pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

A value in Lua can be *anywhere*. It can be in many different places at once. Indeed, your code clearly shows it:

```lua
shape_a = player.shape
```

The `shape` table is now in two places: the global table (under the name `shape_a`) and the `player` table (under the name `shape`).

Values can be in local variables, which don't actually have names (not once the compiler is through with them.

What you want is generally not possible.

Comment: OK, so I have different objects (which are tables), and they have shapes. The collision library I'm using has a callback function that returns what shapes are colliding, and I want to use that to call a function in the instance the shape is in. Can you think of any good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about box2D or Chipmunk physics. (I am referring to the comment in Nicol Bolas reply).

Both of them have a way to do that provided, if I remember well, in Chipmunk (it is my guess about what you are using) there are a data field.

From Chipmunk manual:

```
cpDataPointer cpBodyGetUserData(const cpBody *body)
void cpBodySetUserData(cpBody *body, const cpDataPointer value)
```

> User data pointer. Use this pointer to get a reference to the game
> object that owns this body from callbacks.

Comment: I am actually not using a physics engine, I am using HardonCollider with Love2D.